# Funcion =TEXTO(celda;"hh:mm") Excel Visual basic

Tags: excel, vba

Estimados, requiero hacer una macro emulando la función =TEXTO() de EXCEL en vb.

la idea es que al tener celdas con horas (7:55) la función vb me transforme a 07:55. Usualmente para ello utilizo =TEXTO(celda,"hh:mm"), esto me la transforma. Necesito llevar esa función a visual basic pero no me funciona con el siguiente código:

```
Sub cambiarFormatohhmm()
Dim celda As Range

    For Each celda In Selection
        celda.Value = Texto(celda,"hh:mm")
    Next

End Sub
```

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba cambiando la línea del `for` para que quede así:

```
Sub cambiarFormatohhmm()
Dim celda As Range

    For Each celda In Selection
        cell.NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub cambiarFormatohhmm()
Dim celda As Range

    For Each celda In Selection
        celda.Value = Format(celda,"hh:mm")
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Una respuesta que es solamente codigo no es muy util pues no explica cual es el problema ni la solucion. Intenta mejor tu respuesta con alguna guia para este o futuros lectores.